# vendor added Product details from products collection table

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have created market place for vendors and vendor added product stored in marketplace_product table.How i can show complete product details like image,description of these products in magento.
I have tried the below code

```
$showcaseproducts       =    Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                                   ->addFieldToSelect( '*' )
                                   ->addFieldToFilter('userid','163')
                                   ->load();
```

But i am not getting the products details

Comment: You need to get specific product detail from product_id right?

Comment: yes ..............

Answer (score 0):

You need to used following code :

```
    $showcaseproducts = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                      ->addFieldToSelect( '*' )
                      ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',163);

foreach($showcaseproducts as $curproduct)
{
     $curproduct->getId(); //HERE YOU CAN ACCESS ALL YOUR TABLE FIELD
}
```

In above code you need to replace "product_id" column with your table column name in which you store product Id.